# Как дождаться завершения всех обещаний?

Tags: javascript

Вот пример. В консоли выводится порядок такой

```
1.1
1.2
-завершились-
3.1
3.2
```

А нужно чтобы

-завершились-

выводилось в конце. Функция  Promise.all я так понял запускает промисы.
А как повесить ожидание, чтобы только когда все промисы выполнились то оно срабатывает?

https://jsfiddle.net/aefuqvkL/

```
var promises = [];

var pr = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('1.1'); 
    resolve(true);
});
 var pr2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('1.2'); 
    resolve(true);
});
promises.push(pr);
promises.push(pr2);


Promise.all(promises).then(values => { 
    console.log('-завершились-'); 
});

setTimeout(function() {
    pr.then(function() {
        console.log('3.1'); 
    }, function() {
        console.log('4.1'); 
    });
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
    pr2.then(function() {
        console.log('3.2'); 
    }, function() {
        console.log('4.2'); 
    });
}, 3000);
```

Comment: если ты ждешь _только_ первые два Promise, почему ты думаешь, что должен ждать оставшиеся два? Обрати внимание, что функция `then` возвращает **новый** Promise

Comment: Ну а что мне использовать чтобы у меня вызвалась функция после того как 2 таймаута истекут? То есть мне это надо. Знать что оба таймаута истекли.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так как сейчас в `Promise.all` передаются только два обещания *pr* и *pr2*, вывод совершенно логичен.

> Функция Promise.all я так понял запускает промисы

Неверно понял. Обещания *запускаются* сразу же при выполнении конструктора.

По сути, следующие выражения эквивалентны:

```
Promise.resolve(true);
new Promise(function(resolve){ resolve(true); });
```

---

Чтобы дождаться обещаний, которые создаются внутри *setTimeout*, нужно их как-то получить.

1. обернуть нужные функции в конструктор `Promise` как есть:

   ```
   var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
       setTimeout(function() {
           pr.then(function() {
               console.log('3.1'); 
               resolve(true);
           }, function() {
               console.log('4.1'); 
               reject(false);
           });
       }, 1000);
   });
   ```

   и аналогично со вторым setTimeout, и уже эти два обещания передавать в `Promise.all`
2. сделать обертку над `setTimeout` возвращающую обещание:

   ```
   function delay(timeout){
       return new Promise(function(resolve){
           setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
       });
   }
   ```

Тогда код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```js
function delay(timeout) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
  });
}

var pr = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log('1.1');
  resolve(true);
});
var pr2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log('1.2');
  resolve(true);
});

var timeout1 = delay(1000).then(function() {
  return pr;
}).then(function() {
  console.log('3.1');
}, function() {
  console.log('4.1');
});

var timeout2 = delay(3000).then(function() {
  return pr2;
}).then(function() {
  console.log('3.2');
}, function() {
  console.log('4.2');
});

var promises = [timeout1, timeout2];

Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
  console.log('-завершились-');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но вот как то всё усложнено. Хотя мне просто надо сделать вызов функции когда и 1 и 2 таймаут завершаться. То есть синхронизировать ассинхронный код.. Я думал в es6 есть какие нибудь инструменты под это удобные. Или только так?

Comment: @manking, в чем именно сложность? ты все так же создаешь два обещания и ждешь их. У тебя проблема в том была, что ты не те обещания ждал